# Are these whites flecks anything to be concerned about? What are they?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

I recently took in this neglected plant and for a while (during the summer) it flowered well and seemed happy. More recently however the flowers dried and fell off and these white flecks appeared. They don't seem to move so I don't think they are bugs (though I could be wrong) but I'm not sure if they are a concern or if the plant is thriving anymore.

We live in Cheshire, UK.

Additional note: I have been giving the plant water with banana peel in it occasionally as the other plants seemed to like it. Perhaps this was a mistake.

[image: Houseplant with small yellow flowers and white marks on the leaves]

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to add a photo where the flecks are in focus? I know it can be tricky, but it would be helpful to confirm: I am quite sure that they are in fact insects. And not the kind you want to have there or on the other plants. In any case, keep this plant quarantined.

Answer (score 1):

These are aphids and the dry shells where they have moulted.  They drink plant juice and cluster around where the plant growth is strongest.

Control is easy:

- Fill your sink with dish soap and water (5 ml per liter) so you can dip the plant in the solution.
- Leave in the water for 30 seconds
- Remove and rinse with fresh water
- Repeat every five days at least another two times, more if they return

Answer (score 0):

While those could be aphid skins, as kevinskio said, the picture isn't very clear. So, it could be mealy bugs, which are also white (and they may not appear to be insects, even though they are). If either of those things is the problem, yes, it is an issue that you'll need to take care of (or it may eventually kill your plant).

Aphid skins would be loosely on the leaves. Mealy bugs would be more attached, and look more cottony.